# How does torch.cuda.synchronize() behave?

Tags: python, pytorch

According to the PyTorch [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cuda.synchronize.html) `torch.cuda.synchronize` "Waits for all kernels in all streams on a CUDA device to complete.". Questions:

1. Should this say "Waits for all kernels in all streams **initiated by this Python session** on a CUDA device to complete"? In other words, if Python session A is running CUDA operations, and I call `torch.cuda.synchronize()` in Python session B, that **won't** care about what's happening in Python session A right?
2. Surely if we don't call `torch.cuda.synchronize()`, but try to work with any python code referencing the tensors in the computation graph, then it's like implicitly calling it right?

Q2 in code:

```
output = model(inputs)  # cuda starts working here
a = 1 + 1  # cuda might still be running the previous line. This line can run at the same time
other_model(output) # This implicitly does the same thing as torch.cuda.synchronize() then does a forward pass of other_model
b = a + a  # This line can't happen until cuda is done and the previous line has been executed
```